# how to boot windows 7 installation from pxelinux

Tags: boot, windows, pxe

I try and fail to successfully boot into windows 7 (x64) installation from network. The PXE server I used in based on `pxelinux` and `tftp-hda`.

I follow this guide https://blog.hmkruse.de/2016/01/28/Installing-Windows-7-with-a-PXE-boot-server/ but I get the following error

[image]

that is `File: \Boot\BCD , Status: 0xc0000001`

This error does pop up in the internet but none of the solutions helped. So I fired up `tcpdump port 69` to check was is going on:

```
03:04:54.438733 IP <...>:  41 RRQ "message.txt" octet tsize 0 blksize 1408 
03:04:58.845116 IP <...>:  45 RRQ "Boot/startrom.0" octet tsize 0 blksize 1408 
03:04:58.868300 IP <...>:  33 RRQ "bootmgr.exe" octet blksize 1456 
03:04:59.942315 IP <...>:  42 RRQ "\Boot\Fonts\wgl4_boot.ttf" octet tsize 0 
03:04:59.972947 IP <...>:  26 RRQ "\boot.ini" octet tsize 0 
03:05:15.217769 IP <...>:  26 RRQ "\Boot\BCD" octet tsize 0  
03:05:15.224985 IP <...>:  39 RRQ "\Boot\BCD" octet tsize 0 blksize 1420 
03:05:15.239790 IP <...>:  42 RRQ "\Boot\Fonts\wgl4_boot.ttf" octet tsize 0
```

I definitely do not have a "boot.ini" file in my windows boot folder. I do have the rest of the files though (those explained in the link too).

Have you had this problem ? Does it ring a bell? Why can the boot procedure complete?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: _Why will Windows 7 not boot for me?_ really is not a Unix nor a Linux question.

Comment: @JdeBP all the configuration is done on the linux side though and also where the error (probably) lies as well

Answer (score 1):

/etc/xinetd.d/tftpd file make this change

```
server_args             = -vvv -m /etc/remap.cfg
```

Then create the file /etc/remap.cfg

```
# The purpose of this file is to do some remapping of the incoming
# tftp requests in the cases where we can identify the incoming client
#  (i.e. in the case of Windows).  This helps us achieve a better organization
#  in the tftp directory structure.
#
# Remap all paths starting with \ to lowercase.  This normalizes
#   all windows tftp requests to lowercase files.
#   We also prefix "\winpe" to the request.
r  ^\\(.*)$ \\\Lwinpe\\\1
# Remap all \ path separators to / (Windows to Unix style)
rg  \\  /
```